# Deploy WPF with Kudu?

Tags: wpf, azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, kudu

I have a solution with multiple projects. One of them is a WPF project, which I'd like to deploy via Kudu.

I have set the desired project [to be deployed via app settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#using-app-settings-instead-of-a-deployment-file) as per kudu doc instructions. E.g. `WebProject/WebProject.csproj`

But kudu deploys the wrong project, because it is the before-mentioned WPF/Windows Application type.

Is there a way where I can make some sort of configuration, so kudu can build my WPF project and deploy it?

Comment: if you explicitly specified the project, it would either build that or failed (likely the latter since we don't support WPF project type).  It is strange that it built the wrong project altogether.  Try looking at the deployment log under D:\home\site\deployments.   This should have the details of the deployment steps.   Eventually, you might end up copy and customize the deploy.cmd to build the WPF project.  Hope this helps,

Comment: @SuwatCh I'll definitely take at look at the log. Thanks, I'll update my question when I have learned more :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this guide](https://elbruno.com/2013/06/01/azure-howto-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-and-azure-website/), which worked quite brilliantly.

Basically you simple build your WPF project on your local machine, and put the output files in a MVC project folder. You then use Kudu to deploy your MVC project, and from there you can see your WPF application.

Just remember to include your WPF build files in the WPF project, since they will be excluded by default.